# Why can't I add or edit contacts on my new iPhone 4?

Tags: contacts, ios

On my new iPhone 4, I can add a new contact after talking to them (Add as new contact) but I cannot otherwise add new contacts, or edit existing ones.

It looks like a bug.  Is there a way to work around it, or do I have to wait for Apple to fix their issue?  The phone is not jailbroken.

Comment: Perhaps it is because I restored a backup from my old 3GS to the new phone?  Either way, the + button in the Contacts app isn't there, and neither is the Edit button when I look at a contact...

Comment: There is an issue. When going through the contacts app I am unable to add, edit or delete contacts. I also tried going through my text messages to edit the contact from there and was unable to. But if I go through the phone app and select favorites or numbers that I have recently called, then I am able to edit those contacts. Is this a minor glitch? Before the new software update to my iPhone 4 I was able to edit contacts through selecting my contact book and through txt messages.

Comment: Make sure Contacts is closed and removed from the multitasking menu (double tap home button). Then open it and take a screenshot (power + home button). Post that screenshot please.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Contacts application provided in the iPhone 4, and create/edit contacts in there.

Comment: On a brand-new iPhone 4, the Contacts application is the only built-in application on the *second* app screen. Swipe to the right and you should see it.

Answer (score 3):

What's preventing you from doing so?

The ability to add and edit contacts from the phone app is still available.  I tested this just now on mine.

Comment: I can't do that; the + button is missing on mine!

Comment: Are you syncing your contacts with any sources?  Please check Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars and see if any accounts say "Contacts" underneath.

Comment: -1 - how on earth is "it works on mine" a valid answer? (Except, even though I've got 20k+ global rep, I still can't downvote here. So it's in spirit only)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem occurs when adding contacts to these phones after updating to IOS 5 (the + sign on the corner right is missing).  IOS 5 added iCloud and if your contacts are not turned ON from the iCloud settings, you won't be able to add, edit or delete contacts.

The Fix: turn ON your iCloud contacts settings from Settings > iCloud and you should see your + sign on the corner back again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. Go to settings, then iCloud, go to the 'contacts' switch and set it to 'on' and it will fix your problem immediately.

Answer (score -2):

just go to settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > if there is a accont (hotmail, g mail etc.) just delete the account and then  automatically you can start adding contacts

Comment: an anonymous commenter adds this: " this just deletes your mail account... see below answers regarding icloud settings for IOS5 and above... I followed this step and now having to re-configure my mail settings...."

Comment: Citing sources is a helpful practice for tips like this.